# C# and Unity, keep original index in relation to sorted array of integers

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, unity-game-engine

I seen similar posts but nothing was really close to how I'm doing things so I made another post. I'm building a scoreboard for a map I'm making in VRChat and in case someone is not familiar with how that goes, VRChat limits what people can do with C# so I can't use lists, dictionaries, or do convenient things like import the System library and use Array.Sort() or Array.Reverse() and so on.

I used my own sorting method to get an array of player scores in descending order but the original index positions of the scores is important to keep consistent with the array of players ID's. So I need to know where the current score index was in relation to where it is after being sorted. for example {10, 20, 30, 40, 15} would be sorted {40, 30, 20, 15, 10} and I need reference to where the original order of scores are now in the sorted array, so I would make a indexSorted array that I need to give me back {3, 2, 1, 4, 0}

I'm now working on the nested for loop to get that data for me. So I keep the original array and make a copy so that I can compare array elements against each other to get the data. It seems to be working for the most part but I'm having a slight issue. The following code uses test data so I can get the algorithm working first before I implement it into my map and for the convenience of replicating my code and trying to help me figure out what's going wrong.

Output of indexSorted array: {4, 3, 1, 2, -1, 5}  -1 indicates there was an issue in the loop but the logic seems to make sense to me so I can't figure out what it's doing wrong. indexSorted keeps track of index's already checked so I don't want to populate the array with any positive integer or 0

````
public void SortNamesAndScores()
    {
        int[] scores1 = new int[] { 50, 100, 100, 150, 200, 25 };
        //copy of original array but sorted in decending order
        int[] scores2 = new int[] { 200, 150, 100, 100, 50, 25 };

        //populate array elements with -1 so if something goes wrong -1 will be an indicator
        for (int x = 0; x < indexSorted.Length; x++)
        {
            indexSorted[x] = -1;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < scores2.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < scores2.Length; j++)
            {
                Debug.Log("outside if statement");
                if (i != indexSorted[j])
                {
                    Debug.Log("inside if statement");
                    if (scores2[i] == scores1[j])
                    {
                        Debug.Log("inside second if statement");
                        indexSorted[i] = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Debug.Log("sorted index");
        foreach (int index in indexSorted)
        {
            Debug.Log(index);
        }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: lol
alright thanks for the advice

Comment: Not a problem :)

Comment: Have you tried [Debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) this? And just for my understanding again: Why can't you use the "normal" c# ways? And is this really related to Unity in specific?

Comment: @derHugo yeah it's more Unity specific and the reason I cant use some features of C# in unity is because I'm making a map for a game called VRChat and they limit what you can do in Unity to prevent from map makers writing malicious code and what not. and in doing so they actually limit quite a few convenience things too which is very unfortunate

Comment: Still what would hinder you from having a `public class score { public int value; }` and then rather work with `score[]` ? Due to reference equality you would immediately know which two entries are equal without getting duplicate indices like with direct `int` value equality ;)

Comment: @derHugo You're probably right but let me try to explain why I've set it up like this. VRChat is a multiplayer game and they have networking events that allow you as a map creator to decide what variables are synced to be global. anything not synced is local to the player in the world and changes are not reflected on to others. So how it works is that the owner of all GameObjects by default is the first person in the world

Comment: so in my case it's the scoreboard with a script attached to it which has two arrays for player names and player scores that need to be synced to all other players and display on the scoreboard. The local players can't pass data to the owner specifically so you can transfer ownership to other players in code if it's necessary, so in my case each player has their own local score but when I need their score to be added to a global array the ownership needs to be transferred to them so that they can update their own score in the global array of scores and sort the data to be displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as derHugo wrote, your algorithm is wrong, especially this line:

```
if (i != indexSorted[j])
```

Because of this line, the 5th element is skipped. It doesn't even make sense to compare indexes like this, since you are comparing the index from the first loop => i with value of array with index from second loop => indexSorted[j].

This means, that when you have value of 4 => index of score 200 as a first element of indexSorted array, and you are in the 5th iteration in your first for loop, the 5th item => score 50 will just be skipped. That's why you have -1 in your array.

Simplest fix is to edit your code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < scoresTemp2.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < scoresTemp1.Length; j++)
    {
        if (scoresTemp1[j] == scoresTemp2[i])
        {
            indexSorted[i] = j;
            scoresTemp1[j] = -1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

With this change, the element from first array with score that has already been checked will be changed to -1, so it won't be compared again. The output is:

```
4
3
1
2
0
5
```

If you can't change first array like this, then just create a copy of the first array and work with that. Or you can use another for loop, as derHugo mentioned previously.

Comment: Yeah I should be able to change the first array, so this solution worked for me. Thank you very much I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand your limitations but in general it would probably be better to keep these already together in one class and sort these elements based on the scores.

I think there is a logic mistake in your checks.

I did some debugging

```
    int[] scoresTemp1 = new int[] { 50, 100, 100, 150, 200, 25 };
    //copy of original array but sorted in decending order
    int[] scoresTemp2 = new int[] { 200, 150, 100, 100, 50, 25 };

    int[] indexSorted = new int[6];

    //populate array elements with -1 so if something goes wrong -1 will be an indicator
    for (int x = 0; x < indexSorted.Length; x++)
    {
        indexSorted[x] = -1;
    }

    //get index of the scoresTemp array for pairing id's to match scores

    for (int i = 0; i < scoresTemp2.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < scoresTemp1.Length; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\n\ni:{i} - j:{j} - indexSorted[j]: {indexSorted[j]}");
            if (i != indexSorted[j])
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{i} != {indexSorted[j]}");
                Console.WriteLine($"scoresTemp2[{i}]={scoresTemp2[i]} - scoresTemp1[{j}]={scoresTemp1[j]}");
                if (scoresTemp2[i] == scoresTemp1[j])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{scoresTemp2[i]} == {scoresTemp1[j]} => indexSorted[{j}] = {i}");
                    indexSorted[i] = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

  
    foreach (int index in indexSorted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(index);
    }
 }
```

Which outputs the following

```
i:0 - j:0 - indexSorted[j]: -1
0 != -1
scoresTemp2[0]=200 - scoresTemp1[0]=50


i:0 - j:1 - indexSorted[j]: -1
0 != -1
scoresTemp2[0]=200 - scoresTemp1[1]=100


i:0 - j:2 - indexSorted[j]: -1
0 != -1
scoresTemp2[0]=200 - scoresTemp1[2]=100


i:0 - j:3 - indexSorted[j]: -1
0 != -1
scoresTemp2[0]=200 - scoresTemp1[3]=150


i:0 - j:4 - indexSorted[j]: -1
0 != -1
scoresTemp2[0]=200 - scoresTemp1[4]=200
200 == 200 => indexSorted[4] = 0


i:1 - j:0 - indexSorted[j]: 4
1 != 4
scoresTemp2[1]=150 - scoresTemp1[0]=50


i:1 - j:1 - indexSorted[j]: -1
1 != -1
scoresTemp2[1]=150 - scoresTemp1[1]=100


i:1 - j:2 - indexSorted[j]: -1
1 != -1
scoresTemp2[1]=150 - scoresTemp1[2]=100


i:1 - j:3 - indexSorted[j]: -1
1 != -1
scoresTemp2[1]=150 - scoresTemp1[3]=150
150 == 150 => indexSorted[3] = 1


i:2 - j:0 - indexSorted[j]: 4
2 != 4
scoresTemp2[2]=100 - scoresTemp1[0]=50


i:2 - j:1 - indexSorted[j]: 3
2 != 3
scoresTemp2[2]=100 - scoresTemp1[1]=100
100 == 100 => indexSorted[1] = 2


i:3 - j:0 - indexSorted[j]: 4
3 != 4
scoresTemp2[3]=100 - scoresTemp1[0]=50


i:3 - j:1 - indexSorted[j]: 3


i:3 - j:2 - indexSorted[j]: 1
3 != 1
scoresTemp2[3]=100 - scoresTemp1[2]=100
100 == 100 => indexSorted[2] = 3


i:4 - j:0 - indexSorted[j]: 4


i:4 - j:1 - indexSorted[j]: 3
4 != 3
scoresTemp2[4]=50 - scoresTemp1[1]=100


i:4 - j:2 - indexSorted[j]: 1
4 != 1
scoresTemp2[4]=50 - scoresTemp1[2]=100


i:4 - j:3 - indexSorted[j]: 2
4 != 2
scoresTemp2[4]=50 - scoresTemp1[3]=150


i:4 - j:4 - indexSorted[j]: -1
4 != -1
scoresTemp2[4]=50 - scoresTemp1[4]=200


i:4 - j:5 - indexSorted[j]: -1
4 != -1
scoresTemp2[4]=50 - scoresTemp1[5]=25


i:5 - j:0 - indexSorted[j]: 4
5 != 4
scoresTemp2[5]=25 - scoresTemp1[0]=50


i:5 - j:1 - indexSorted[j]: 3
5 != 3
scoresTemp2[5]=25 - scoresTemp1[1]=100


i:5 - j:2 - indexSorted[j]: 1
5 != 1
scoresTemp2[5]=25 - scoresTemp1[2]=100


i:5 - j:3 - indexSorted[j]: 2
5 != 2
scoresTemp2[5]=25 - scoresTemp1[3]=150


i:5 - j:4 - indexSorted[j]: -1
5 != -1
scoresTemp2[5]=25 - scoresTemp1[4]=200


i:5 - j:5 - indexSorted[j]: -1
5 != -1
scoresTemp2[5]=25 - scoresTemp1[5]=25
25 == 25 => indexSorted[5] = 5

4
3
1
2
-1
5
```

Now look closely at the case `i:4 - j:0` (the value `50` we are missing). The `indexSorted[0]` happens to be already index `4` (the value `200`)

=> This item is skipped!

Comment: Oh wow, yeah I see that it skips over that now. Thank you for the help, I appreciate it